# Is there a word for Energizingness?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a single word that means the "degree by which something is energizing". In a sentence:

> On a scale of 1 to 10, how would you rate the _______ of this coffee?
>
> This percentage represents the energy drink's perceived _______.

**This should apply to any such food**, like energy drinks/bars, candy, etc.

But it seems *Energizingness* [is not](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/search?filter=dictionary&query=energizingness) [an English](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/energizingness) [word](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=energizingness). **Is there a word for this?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53658/discussion-on-question-by-supuhstar-is-there-a-word-for-energizingness).

Comment: Some points: 1) Not every word created out of 'legal' affixes is listed in every dictionary (sometimes in no dictionary) but may still be acceptable. 2) in the unix word list /usr/dict/words, there are 347 words ending in '...ingness' 3) However 'X-ingness' endings sound somewhat inarticulate. (the only one I found natural ws 'willingness'). Usually there is an established, common word like 'X-ment' or 'X-ity' (or a different root without affix) or the sentence can be reworded to avoid the infelicity

Answer (score 24):

Are we forgetting how we

> rate the **potency** of this coffee?

*the power of something to influence or make an impression.*

stimulation resulting in an energizing effect on the person and/or his/her body and mind would be the impression or influence the substance in question has. This seems most appropriate of a word for what is essentially a drug. It is a clinical term as well as in my impression, pop culture lingo.

In short, potency packs the most oomph for a single word to describe what your trying to say without "izingness"ing us up yet another dictionary word.

- edit: also potency is appropriate when we are actually objectively asking someone about the coffee, the individual asked would then default to which aspect of the coffee is important and most apparent to them to answer as to the flavors effect or its neurological impact or both.

Comment: I'm not convinced that 'potency' would automatically be interpreted, in that context, as 'degree to which *energy* is imparted/stimulated'. Why wouldn't it as readily be interpreted as referring to strength of flavour? After all, flavour makes an impression.

Comment: I was not convinced either, which is why the words use seems even more appropriate for use in multiple contexts or where the asker does not wish to illicit an opinion on one particular aspect of the coffee. This is outlined in my edit at the bottom.

Comment: I think potency is the best answer so far.  My response to the doubts of @Spagirl is that at or just before work at least, the flavor of the coffee is incidental (unless it is horrible) and it is the potency that is all important.  Decaf is pointless, IMO.

Comment: @ab2 I understand that that is how you might feel of a morning, but it might well *not* be how someone else feels about a post-prandial expresso. The question was not dependent on the time of day or mood of the person being asked. I appreciate that although I think this answer falls well short of meeting the question requirements, it has been well upvoted and its one of those situations where my tendency to be very literal puts me out of step with the crowd!

Comment: I don't think this is quite the right word, either. Suppose I gave you two cups of the same coffee, but one cup is twice as big as the other. Both cups are equally potent (it's the same coffee), but the larger one imparts a greater energizing effect.

Comment: potency could refer to its taste or effect imo, and in practice your critique could apply to any of the answers so far. who knows if a sip or a cup,or 5 would be the basis from which the respondent answers. I do  think potency has some implication that one is speaking about of the caffeine not the taste but that depends. without me further tearing my own answer apart, it should be noted caffeine does not necessarily induce an energizing effect on some people, I have known some on the contrary to become drowsy. this was my first answer on this site so im just happy it was a suitable one.

Comment: essentially i dont think there is a perfect word that works in all possible contexts and possible interpretations, but this one jives with me

Answer (score 12):

You could simply reformulate the sentence

> On a scale of 1 to 10, how ***energising*** would you rate this coffee?`

Comment: Or ***energizing*** in the U.S. Considering that the OP spelled it with a 'z', that's what he's looking for.

Comment: *On a scale from 1 to 10, how energizing/energising would you rate this coffee **to be**?*

Answer (score 11):

In the context of coffee, I'd probably use **Strength**, which is generally understood to correspond to how "awake" the coffee makes you feel.

Comment: Like strength, **Power** has the same effect. Anything along the links of measuring energy.

Comment: Power works too, but I think strength is more specific to coffee.

Comment: That's why I just added it as a comment, instead. Just expounding on the fact that there are lots of words that embody a measure of energy.

Comment: Perhaps... I normally associate the "Strength" of coffee with its flavor or bitterness, rather than its ability to energize me.

Comment: @Supuhstar Another reason for my suggestion of power is because of the definition in physics, "amount of energy consumed per unit time". This would describe not only the amount of energy, but could also be used to reference how long until it takes effect or how long it will keep you going.

Comment: @Supuhstar I was actually worried about that; the meaning I've always heard it interpreted as refers to the "strength" of the caffeine, but after searching I came across this: http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/44/what-does-the-strength-mean-in-numbers

It sort of shows there's more to the caffeinating power of a brew than what the brand defines. That said, I couldn't think of any other appropriate word to do with coffee so I'll stand by my answer until something more accurate comes up.

Comment: Around here (Melbourne), I interpret "strength" as the ratio of coffee to water/milk. A "strong" coffee has more coffee than the usual at that cafe (could be 2 shots vs 1, 3 vs 2, or 1 long vs 1 normal). So, for me, "a strong decaf" is perfectly sensible.

Answer (score 7):

*On a scale of 1 to 10, how would you rate the* **efficacy** *of this coffee?*

**Efficacy** is a somewhat more technical term, style-wise. I would recommend **strength** in the specific case of a poll about coffee, as monoRed suggested. But "efficacy" might be more appropriate in other cases. It's more general than "energizingness", and shorter than "effectiveness". As mentioned in another comment, "potency" is also roughly synonymous with "efficacy" here.

Comment: Oooh I like **potency**

Comment: Surely that only means 'effective'? I can#t be the only person who primarily drinks coffee because I like the taste of it rather than solely for the purpose of becoming 'energised'? What I mean is that 'becoming energised' doesn't have the one-to-one relationship with people drinking coffee that, say, removal of pain has with people taking paracetemol. So efficacy seems a poor fit.

Comment: Well, as I said, "efficacy" is more general than "energizingness". Food or drugs can bear efficacy in energizing you, relieving pain, inducing vomiting, etc. A person can bear efficacy in completing paperwork, folding laundry, etc. "Efficacy" is interchangeable with "effectiveness", aye; I find the former rolls better off the tongue.

Comment: @PaulBrinkley So we agree that efficacy means effectiveness, but you don't address my point that 'energisingness' is not the only 'effect' that may be sought from coffee. One takes a pain killer to relieve pain. if it does that it is efficient. One*may* drink coffee, to quench thirst, to enjoy the flavour, to be sociable, to benefit from the effects of caffiene. It isn't a one-to-one mapping as painkiller-pain relief is. For some people deceff wil be efficacious for all but one aspect of the list.

Comment: That energy is but one of many effects sought from coffee is a natural implication of "food or drugs can bear efficacy in energizing you, relieving pain, inducing vomiting, etc." and a "person can bear efficacy in completing paperwork, folding laundry, etc.".

Answer (score 7):

***oomph***

[Your Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/oomph) says:

> An example of oomph is how someone feels after drinking a double shot
>   of espresso.

And [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oomph) says:

> punch, vitality
>
> Example in Sentence: The truck doesn't have the oomph to haul the boat

Answer (score 6):

If you are wedded to this sentence structure, one possibility might be **invigoration**, the noun form of the verb **invigorate**, which means "to give life and energy to" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/invigorate)).

However, it would probably be less awkward to rephrase the sentence entirely as something like: "on a scale of 1 to 10, how invigorating [*or: how energizing*] did you find this coffee?"

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes two words are better than one: **energy boost**

> How much **energy boost** is in one espresso?
>    On a scale of 1 to 10, how would you rate the **energy boost** of this coffee?

The expression “energy boost” is used in the following articles:

http://www.livestrong.com/article/410802-black-coffees-effects-on-the-body/
http://alifeofproductivity.com/get-more-energy-out-of-caffeine/

But if it *really* has to be one word, then write it with a hyphen: **energy-boosting coffee**

Comment: So far this is the best fit for my use-case!

Answer (score 3):

Just in a natural setting the first thing that would come to my head to get that 'feeling' across would be just the slang 'kick'.

"How would you rate the kick of this coffee?"

I mostly base this off of the fact that it's been a common thing I've said my whole life, to be honest, such as, "Wow there's some kick in this, what did you put in it?" I tend to find it synonymous with 'zest' in a way, except more abrupt and leaning into that it gives you a jolt you weren't expecting.

On that note, for the feeling of this question to be honest I'd say even 'zest' would fit in, as an example: "On a scale of one to ten, how much zest is in the flavor of the coffee?"  Saying that out-loud does tend to hit the ear a little wrong for this application, but, it's not out of the ballpark. Technically you'd attribute zest to more of a refreshing kind of taste usually with food, kinda goes with tangy, but just wanted to put it out there in case maybe that's word that would hit the nail on the head for you.

Altogether, if the question could be altered slightly, it seems like if you tossed out: "On a scale of one to ten, how much of a kick does this coffee have?" Running that through a voice-over here a few times for an imaginary interview seems like something a marketing department would eat up, given trendy buzz-style (and often coming across as a forced 'casual' soft-ball Broadcast commercial conversation) word choice.

That aside, if it were you and I sitting across from one another and you just put that out there with 'kick', I'd lock in on exactly what you meant. But, it could entirely just be me, or the area of the U.S. I'm from; the biggest factor that lead me to 'kick' is my experience in Broadcast FM Radio, and having to record commercials for various things. Definitely had a few small cafes or the like in the past buy airtime and toss me a script rather than asking me to come up with it for them. I've used 'kick' in at least one I'm almost 100% positive, but it's been awhile.

Apologies for the long-winded explanation, just wanted to give a decent idea of where my thought process was going with the word choices.

Hope this at least gets some other's thoughts going if nothing else, and I'll toss it around in my head today and see what else I can come up with.

Comment: I like your arguments!

Answer (score 3):

"On a scale of 1 to 10, how [**rejuvenating**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rejuvenate) do you find this coffee?"

> to make someone look or feel young and energetic again

*Cambridge Dictionary*

We're particularly focusing on the "feel" and "energetic" parts of definition. It's fairly common (though perhaps overly verbose) to say 'I feel rejuvenated when I have my morning cup of coffee'.

Answer (score 2):

Although *energizingness* is not a word, *[refreshingness](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/refreshingness)* is and fits well what you are looking for. It is *the quality of being refreshing* [Oxford].

Comment: I would interpret this very differently: as how tart the flavor and light/'clean' the mouthfeel was, and not at all on how energizing or caffeinated it felt.

Comment: The primary meaning of Refresh in MW is to restore strength and animation to...

Answer (score 1):

Like [Alex said](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/373630/2294), even I was of the opinion that the key is in reformulating the sentence:

> On a scale of 1 to 10, how energized did you feel after drinking this
>   coffee?

I believe the objective is to capture how the guest felt, and the above sentence captures the emotion of the guest and also the word that the OP wanted to use.

Comment: The word will be used in a table column header for a survey about energy drinks, alongside `flavor` and `smoothness`, so `energized` doesn't really work :c

Comment: If `flavor` was used instead of `flavouriness`, then `energy` would be the right word. Mari-Lou's "energy boost" is also good.

Comment: well, the difference is that the coffee has the flavor... I don't think it has the energy. It's more that it has chemical that you use to make energy.

Answer (score 1):

"Zing" means vitality, like other words mentioned, but furthermore the excitation of other things or people, therefore it's a good fit (especially if you want to keep the sentence as it is).

The first meaning is "vitality, animation, or zest" and the second meaning
"a quality or characteristic that excites the interest, enthusiasm, etc" (from dictionary.com).

Answer (score -1):

"Briskness" is used to describe the magnitude of the stimulating tendencies of tea. I can't think of a reason to not use it for coffee too.

Comment: I've never heard the word "brisk" used to describe the stimulating properties of tea, and I can't find any reference to it online. The only thing I see is a tea product by the name "Brisk", manufactured by Lipton, and even there, I can't see any evidence that the name "brisk" means it is extra-stimulating (*e.g.*, that it has extra caffeine).

Comment: brisk is used to denote a quality of flavour, rather than provision of energy.http://www.teadiscussion.com/various/tea-tasting-terminology-explained.php

Comment: I thought you might be confusing briskness with brackishness, which is used to describe unpleasant tea. Fine, brisk could be used to describe tea by connoisseurs, but in my opinion it is disingenuous to recommend this word to describe tea in an everyday situation. I think context matters. Whilst a native speaker using brisk may be seen as an enigmatic connoisseur, a non-native speaker may just be seen as having confused the word with something else.

Answer (score -1):

How about ***effectiveness***.
how would you rate the effectiveness of this coffee?

[Effectiveness](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/effectiveness)